# Using IF and conditional formatting

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to have a cell becoming highlighted if it satisfies two criteria.

I would like the cells below each Staff column to be purple if its both the same as the version# and contains *.
I've managed to highlight cells containing the * by using "highlight if cells contain" ~* but I can't get it to do both.

[image: Image of excel table in question highlighting cells containing *]

I've tried

`=AND(L2=$J2,"~*")`

`=AND($J2,"~*")`

`=IF(AND(L2=$J2,"~*"))`

(Version# is column J, Staff 1 is column L)

Comment: You need to use the 'Formula to determine which cells to format' option. It doesn't look like the Version# contains an asterisk, so they won't both be true.

Comment: If the Staff # contains an asterisk, will it always immediately follow the version #? If so you could just do `=L2=$J2&"*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by BigBen

If the Staff # contains an asterisk, will it always immediately follow the version #? If so you could just do
`=L2=$J2&"*"`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing what I think you want, the main issue is the asterisk. When you enter a number in a cell and also enter a non-numerical character the cell automatically becomes formatted as TEXT. It is possible to extract the numerical value with a formula, but handling what you want is much easier if you separate the number from the asterisk. In my included example (You should be able to open it in a new tab on your browser) created narrow columns after each 'staff#' column to accept the asterisk entry.
This done, enter the three conditional formats as shown (in C2 in the example). You then copy the C2 cell into each of the cells under the Staff# columns. That produced the results shown which I think is what you want. Changing entries will produce the proper formatting results for that cell.

Comment: That would work but I'm wanting to make the sheet as easy to use as possible as I'll be distributing it to other departments so the less work required by the user the better!